# if $a^{(p-1)/2}$≡ -1(mod p) then the order of a mod p is p-1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove

Suppose that p is an odd prime , if $a^{(p-1)/2}$≡ -1(mod p) then the order of a mod p is p-1

I think it is true statement , $a^{(p-1)/2}$≡ -1(mod p) by squaring both side we get $a^{(p-1)}$≡ 1(mod p) then the order of a mod p is p-1

is that right answer ?

Comment: Note that the order is the least integer $n$ such that $a^n\equiv 1$.

Comment: Try $p=11$ and $a=10$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector , do you mean the statement is false not true and p=11 and a=10 is counterexample?thank you

Comment: $10^2\equiv1\pmod{11}$, so $10$ has order $2$. So that **is** a counterexample.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, I think it is not correct counterexample because it does not fit the question ?? please see it to me

Comment: What exactly doesn't fit? Do you agree that $11$ is an odd prime? Do you agree that $10^{(11-1)/2}=10^5\equiv-1\pmod{11}$, because $10^5+1=100001=11\cdot9091$? So where's your problem?

Comment: @ProfessorVector , Do you mean the result that the order of 10 mod 11 is 5 not 10 ?thank you very much

Comment: As I wrote in plain text and showed by calculation, the order of $10$ is ${\color{red}2}$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, sorry but I do not see the calculation for that ?

Comment: You didn't see $10^2\equiv1\pmod{11}$ in my comment? What were you replying to, then? That's enough, now. Don't ask again.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false: $a$ has order $p-1$ iff $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is the *smallest* exponent $k$ such that $a^k=-1$.

So, for a counterexample, we have to find $a$ with even order $n< p-1$. Then $a^{n/2}=-1$. Moreover, to get $a^{(p-1)/2}=-1$, we need $(p-1)/n$ to be odd.

Now, $a=p-1$ always has order $2$. Therefore, the easiest counterexample is $a=p-1$, when $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ because then $(p-1)/2$ is odd.

There are some more interesting counterexamples which have $n>2$:

- $p=13, a=5$. Then $ord(a)=4$.
- $p=19, a=8$. Then $ord(a)=6$.

Counterexamples with $n>2$ exists for these primes:
$$
13,19,29,31,37,41,43,53,61,67,71,73,79,89,97,101,103,109,113,127,131,137,139,\dots
$$
but this sequence is not in OEIS.

These are the primes $p$ such that $p-1=2u$ with $u$ odd composite or $p-1=4v$ with $v >1 $ odd. Then we can take in the first case $n=2w$, where $w$ is a nontrivial factor of $u$, and $n=4$ in the second case.

Comment: do you mean the statement is false not true ?thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $ p =4k +3$. Then $ (p-1)/2 = 2k+1$. Now let $ a= p-1$. Then we see that $ a^2 $ is $1$ modulo $p$. So  order  of $a$ is 2.Also  $ a^{p-1/2} = (p-1)^{2k+1} \equiv -1 $ modulo $p$.(by the expansion ). Thus this is a general counterexample and it is not true.

Comment: do you mean the statement is false not true and p=11 and a=10 is counterexample?thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=7$ and $a=6$. Then $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=6^\frac{7-1}{2}=6^3=216\equiv -1\pmod 7$. But $ord_7(6)=2$. Hope this helps and I think this was a counterexample not shown in the answer above. But correct me if I am wrong.